# Are input fields that don’t have name=“” sent via the browser

Tags: tls, web-application, web-browser, php, credit-card

Are input fields that don’t have `name` attributes susceptible to MITM attacks (w/o SSL) or any other attack?

For example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="credit_card_number"><input id="credit_card_number" type="text" value="4111111111111111"></label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What I'm doing is using javascript to get the values, then posting to stripe.js, receiving a token and then clearing all the values of the CC fields before submitting the form to the server.

I understand that SSL would be a good idea but would it be necessary? And why if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are input fields that don’t have name="" sent via the browser

Not by the standard HTML form submission process. However JavaScript on the client side can read the contents of the fields and send that data themselves.

> Are input fields that don’t have name attributes susceptible to MITM attacks (w/o SSL) or any other attack?

Yes. All content on a page that is not protected by SSL is susceptible to MitM attacks.

Even if stripe.js is reading the credit card number and sending it to Stripe's servers completely securely, there is no way to know that the rest of your page was not tampered with by an active MitM attack at load time. For example, a piece of JavaScript could have been injected into the page which listens for keypresses and sends the credit card number to the attacker separately.

This sort of thing is why the advice to users is always to check that SSL is enabled at the page level, and why PCI-DSS requires that web pages where the user is invited to type a password must show as being SSL-protected in the browser UI.

> I understand that SSL would be a good idea but would it be necessary?

Yes. In any case Stripe [require you to do that](https://support.stripe.com/questions/do-i-need-to-be-pci-compliant-what-do-i-have-to-do).

> - Serve your payment page over SSL, i.e., the page's web address should begin with https, not http.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. Any HTTP request that isn't protected by SSL/TLS/HTTPS is vulnerable to MitM attacks.  Without the integrity that is provided by HTTPS, any component of the HTML served over HTTP is vulnerable to attack or modification by a man-in-the-middle.   For instance, the form's action could be changed, so instead of the form being POSTed to your intended page, it could be POSTed to a page on a malicious site (as designated by the MitM) instead.

The bottom line is that anything you send to the client over HTTP could be changed before it actually gets to the client.  If you need security (and you certainly do for payment transactions) you need HTTPS to ensure that the client is receiving what you intended them to receive.

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to read more on the encryption downstream because it seems as though SSL can't prevent everything if the downstream of content is hijacked.